# JPL hibernate date math

Tags: spring, date, jpa

I'm a Java noob, working in Spring, using Roo-generated models that I've customized.

I need to select the records of a particular type (leases, in this case) that have a "maturationDate" within X days. For display purposes, I've created a `@Transient` property that does the math:

```
@Transient
private Integer daysToMaturation;

@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar2.setTime(this.getMaturesDate());
    calendar1.setTime(new Date());

    long milis1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milis2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

    long day = milis2 - milis1;

    Double diffDays = Math.ceil(day / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    this.daysToMaturation = diffDays.intValue();
}
```

That does okay for output, but now I need to find all records where daysToMaturation <= whatever, and obviously this property doesn't exist until after the query.

JPQL's date functions are tragically primitive. If I could get to raw SQL (perhaps in a `@Formula` field), I could bang this out in a one-liner. What I REALLY want is the ability to say this:

```
@Formula("(select datediff(maturesDate, CURRENT_DATE())")
private Integer daysToMaturation;
```

...but that fails, presumably because I'm not saying `datediff()` to MySQL, I'm saying it to JPA, which never heard of it. It throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested 
exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

And Hibernate logs the following line:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Comment: I think that if you use EclipseLink >=2.1 (instead of Hibernate), you can use the `FUNC()` function to call any database function that is not defined in the JPQL spec.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree date math functions in JPQL are primitive, this problem can easily be circumvented by computing the date corresponding to your "whatever" delay, and comparing the date stored in database to this computed date:

```
int daysToMaturation = 10;
Date maxDate = addDaysToCurrentDate(daysToMaturation);
String jpql = "select lease from Lease lease where lease.maturationDate <= :maxDate";
// ...
```

Comment: I see that. I'mw working on somehow integrating that into the whole framework of what I've got here. Btw... is that "addDaysToCurrentDate()" a real thing, or is that pseudocode?

Comment: It's pseudo-code. Its implementation should be similar to your postLoad method